# Python format tabular output

Tags: python

Using python2.7, I'm trying to print to screen tabular data.

This is roughly what my code looks like:

```
for i in mylist:
   print "{}\t|{}\t|".format (i, f(i))
```

The problem is that, depending on the length of `i` or `f(i)` the data won't be aligned.

This is what I'm getting:

```
|foo |bar |
|foobo   |foobar  |
```

What I want to get:

```
|foo     |bar     |
|foobo   |foobar  |
```

Are there any modules that permit doing this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's not really hard to roll your own formatting function:

```
def print_table(table):
    col_width = [max(len(x) for x in col) for col in zip(*table)]
    for line in table:
        print "| " + " | ".join("{:{}}".format(x, col_width[i])
                                for i, x in enumerate(line)) + " |"

table = [(str(x), str(f(x))) for x in mylist]
print_table(table)
```

Comment: For others' reference, I had to change the format string to "{0:{1}}" to get it to work properly.

Comment: Pylint complains about the * :(. It says "Used * or ** magic".

Comment: Note that this code may not perform correctly if the iterables in table contain any non-string objects, since the len will either not be defined, or may be incorrect. To fix that, change `max(len(x)` to `max(len(str(x))`.

Comment: Not really hard but certainly ugly and unnecessary.

Answer (score 24):

For a more beautiful table, use the tabulate module:

[Tabulate link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate)

Example from the tabulate documentation:

```
>>> from tabulate import tabulate

>>> table = [["Sun",696000,1989100000],["Earth",6371,5973.6],
...          ["Moon",1737,73.5],["Mars",3390,641.85]]
>>> print(tabulate(table))
-----  ------  -------------
Sun    696000     1.9891e+09
Earth    6371  5973.6
Moon     1737    73.5
Mars     3390   641.85
-----  ------  -------------
```

Comment: Yeah, I used this one, and very simple to have a table like structure in just few lines of code!

Answer (score 23):

There is a nice module for this in pypi, PrettyTable.

http://code.google.com/p/prettytable/wiki/Tutorial

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable/

```
$ pip install PrettyTable
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try [BeautifulTable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifultable).
Here's an example:

```
>>> from beautifultable import BeautifulTable
>>> table = BeautifulTable()
>>> table.column_headers = ["name", "rank", "gender"]
>>> table.append_row(["Jacob", 1, "boy"])
>>> table.append_row(["Isabella", 1, "girl"])
>>> table.append_row(["Ethan", 2, "boy"])
>>> table.append_row(["Sophia", 2, "girl"])
>>> table.append_row(["Michael", 3, "boy"])
>>> print(table)
+----------+------+--------+
|   name   | rank | gender |
+----------+------+--------+
|  Jacob   |  1   |  boy   |
+----------+------+--------+
| Isabella |  1   |  girl  |
+----------+------+--------+
|  Ethan   |  2   |  boy   |
+----------+------+--------+
|  Sophia  |  2   |  girl  |
+----------+------+--------+
| Michael  |  3   |  boy   |
+----------+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 8):

```
mylist = {"foo":"bar", "foobo":"foobar"}

width_col1 = max([len(x) for x in mylist.keys()])
width_col2 = max([len(x) for x in mylist.values()])

def f(ind):
    return mylist[ind]

for i in mylist:
    print "|{0:<{col1}}|{1:<{col2}}|".format(i,f(i),col1=width_col1,
                                            col2=width_col2)
```

Comment: It works Thanks. But I'm surprised there are no module to do this natively!

Answer (score 7):

It seems like you want your columns left-justified, but I haven't seen any answers mention the `ljust` string method, so I'll demonstrate that in Python 2.7:

```
def bar(item):
    return item.replace('foo','bar')

width = 20
mylist = ['foo1','foo200000','foo33','foo444']

for item in mylist:
    print "{}| {}".format(item.ljust(width),bar(item).ljust(width))

foo1                | bar1
foo200000           | bar200000
foo33               | bar33
foo444              | bar444
```

For your reference, running `help('abc'.ljust)` gives you this:

> S.ljust(width[, fillchar]) -> string

It looks like the `ljust` method takes your specified width and subtracts the length of the string from that, and pads the right side of your string with that many characters.