# How do I print fields of unpredictable length in a tabular format?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I want to split lines into fields and print them neatly aligned. I do not know in advance how long the names are, so I can't use a fixed format like the ones given in other Stack Overflow questions.

This is the kind of output I would like to get:

```
Simpson, Bartholomew Homer  12345 CSEE       £25000
Jackson, Michael            15675 History    £34000
Clown, Krusty the           56746 Economics  £67000
```

This is the code I have written so far:

```
def printFormat(details):
    details = details.split()
    lastname = details[-1]
    firstnames = " ".join(details[3:-1])
    name = ", ".join([lastname, firstnames])

    ID_Subject = " ".join(details[0:2])
    money = details[2]

    print "%s,%s    %s    %s" % (lastname,firstnames,ID_Subject,money)
```

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909873/python-pretty-printing-ascii-tables) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356501/python-format-tabular-output).

Comment: [Possible answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26005077/5057078), is that what you want?

Comment: no not really i dont know how to apply that logic to my code

Comment: This question should be reopened. It is not a duplicate because it cannot be solved with a fixed format as the linked questions can.