# How to print certain information when reading file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i have this code in python:

```
payment = open ("paintingJobs.txt" , "r")
lines = payment.readlines()
print (lines), ["A"]
```

[Jobs][1]

And, i'm trying to print only the lines of document that contain an **"A"** in them in a suitable format (not scruffy).
I've tried the code above but it just prints out the **whole** document in an unorganised way.

Would there be a way to present the printed info like this: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q68hs.png)

Comment: _"I've tried the code above but it just prints out the whole document in an unorganised way."_ That's strange, that's not what happens when I run it. I just get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on the third line. Are you sure this is the exact code you're running?

Comment: Sorry, was some additional code that i was trying but now, after editing, this i the code im using

Comment: What does "scruffy" mean in this context?

Comment: I'm not gonna click a link labeled *enter link description here*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3437059

Answer (score 0):

`print (lines), ["A"]` is not the correct syntax for printing every element of `lines` that contains the letter A. Instead, try:

```
payment = open ("test.py" , "r")
lines = payment.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if "A" in line:
        print(line)
payment.close()
```

Or, alternatively,

```
payment = open ("test.py" , "r")
lines = payment.readlines()
print([line for line in lines if "A" in line])
payment.close()
```

Comment: Thank You so much and also i would like to ask you if it is possible to present the printed info like this: http://prntscr.com/9wizsd

Comment: I don't see why not. You can use the third party module [Pillow](https://python-pillow.github.io/) to render text onto an image. There isn't going to be a simple one line `render_data_beautifully(payment)` function though, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I mean is there a way to implement .format for the information so it looks like a table, so each bit of info is separated by an equal space hence giving it the appearance of a table.

Comment: You can get nicely spaced columns, yeah. Check out [Python format tabular output](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8356501/953482). You'll probably need to get your data into a two-dimensional list though.

Answer (score 0):

You have use `with`

```
with open("test.py" , "r") as payment
    lines = payment.readlines()
    print([line for line in lines if "A" in line])
```