# Python's tabulate number of decimal

Tags: python, format

Is there a way to define the format style (number of decimals) for the Python module `tabulate` ?

**For example:**

I have the number *3.34643745*.

I want to format the number of decimals to print out only two decimal places.

Output: `3.34`

Comment: Did you [read the overview](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate)? Perhaps Ctrl-F for "decimal" or "number"?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate#number-formatting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python format tabular output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356501/python-format-tabular-output)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes you can do something like:

```
print tabulate([["pi",3.141593],["e",2.718282]], floatfmt=".2f")
```

Which will print:

```
--  ----
pi  3.14
e   2.71
--  ----
```

[Here is a link to the documentation.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate)